# Testing with mochai/ chai , should eventually have NOT resolving promise

Tags: mocha.js, chai

```
  it('should begin with no users', function() {
    return User.find({}).exec().should
      .eventually.have.length(0);
  });
```

Hi, the test fails, but my afterEach and before function clears my users tested and seen through the database. the error message states that cant read have of undefined, which i console logged as a promise. Thus, should.eventually.have is not resolving my promise. some help please.

Comment: What return value is User.find() expected to return and what does it actually return? If your returned Promise does not contain any value, then 'have' will have to work with an undefined value. So debug first by calling `.then` on your result to look what was returned. 
If you have trouble with testing promises and you are running in an environment that supports async/await, look into that, it makes your tests a lot easier to read/understand and you won't need chai as promised anymore.

Comment: As your question is right now, it is not really answerable by people who have no insight in your code as vital information is missing.

Comment: hey @Rhayene ! yeap you were right ! Thank you !

Comment: i solved the issue via using .then ! will paste my code here